# How to enable javascript in tor browser 7.0.2

Tags: security

How do i enable java script on tor browser 7.0.2 so i can see a captcha when signing into a site? I have tried to go into content but there is no option to turn it on/off i have also tried to allow no script on the site but i honestly don't know what i'm doing.

Comment: It's enabled by default.